# Video conversion in java

Tags: java, open-source, video-processing, video-encoding

Is there any framework or open source project for Java that does video conversion from any video format to any video format. Something similar to [Panda](http://pandastream.org/) Video Conversion framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you Mean JMF? - (**Java Media FrameWork**)
Check [**this**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/) out.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of JMF - perhaps this will become to be better alternative: [Freedom for Media in Java](http://fmj-sf.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Checked [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) ?