# video format converter using java

Tags: java, video, video-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931839/video-conversion-in-java)

Hello, I'm exploring ways to interconvert various video formats like avi, flv, wmp using java. Is there any java library there for this??

Thanks and regards,
rohit

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/). It's a wrapper for ffmpeg that works quiet well (depending on what you want it to do, actually)